# Does changing in exposed surface area affect the temperature change of an object in liquid?

Tags: thermodynamics, thermal-conductivity

I am doing an experiment regarding heat transfer. I put aluminium pieces of same mass (about 15.3g) but different exposed surface area. To create this, I cut 4 aluminium pieces into same dimension (16cm x 4cm), then folded them into dimension of (12cm x 4cm), (8cm x 4cm) and (4cm x 4cm). Then I put the pieces in the oven set to 150 ºC. After the temperature is reached, I took the aluminium and dunk it in water (25ºC and about 0.125 kg) while recording the temperature of the water through a temperature sensor.

The results is that we should expect a exponential decay curve from solving Newton's law of cooling.

For the 8cm x 4cm piece (Temperature(ºC) vs time(s)):
[image: Temperature per time curve 8x4]
(Theres a tiny bump shown in the circle but I assumed its uncertainty due to sensor and environmental factors so I considered it as an exponential decay, is it actually uncertainty or related to what explained below?)

This is close to the exponential decay.

But for 4cm x 4cm the (Temperature (ºC) vs time (s)) curve is weird (not really exponential decay).

[image: Temperature per time for 4x4]

There is a noticeable decrease in the temperature of the water after it reach max temperature (a bit before 20 seconds). I thought it may be due to evaporation but I was not sure. What is happening? And at what point do I considered that the heat finish transferred?

Edit 1: Reply to comments on needing relative position of the temperature sensor. Note: the water covers all of the aluminium and the temperature sensor.
[image: Picture of experimental setup]

Comment: Where is your sensor relative to the location of the aluminum pieces?

Comment: I'd like to answer this question tomorrow, it's very late here. Unless someone beats me to it, of course. Questions with empirical data should always be honoured here, I strongly believe.

Comment: It is necessary to submit a photo of the samples, their position in the water, the position of the sensor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's always great to see a contributor actually carrying out some experimentation, so welcome!

However, I feel your experimental protocol leaves somewhat to be desired to.

> I took the aluminium and dunk it in water (25ºC and about 0.125 kg) while recording the temperature of the water through a temperature sensor.

150ºC is higher than the BP of water. It will cause temporary, localised boiling and you don't want that. Don't exceed 100ºC as initial temperature of the $\text{Al}$.

Your pieces of $\text{Al}$ seem very close together, this may reduce the *effective* surface area available for convection. Spread them out more.

Your set-up isn't insulated at all and the shallow water promotes heat loss to the environment. Use something like a styrofoam coffee cup (with lid) to avoid losses.

It may also be simpler and more accurate to measure the temperature increase of the water after some fixed period of time, $\Delta t$.

> (Theres a tiny bump shown in the circle but I assumed its uncertainty
>   due to sensor and environmental factors so I considered it as an
>   exponential decay, is it actually uncertainty or related to what
>   explained below?)

You're assuming exponential evolution of the water temperature because you're thinking of Newton's Cooling Law (I assume). Because here both the water and $\text{Al}$ temperatures change, it's cautious to verify that, as I'll do below.

---

All parameters of $\text{Al}$ are indexed as $1$, all parameters of water are indexed as $2$.

Newton's Cooling Law teaches us that:

$$\frac{\text{d}Q}{\text{d}t}=-hA(T_1-T_2)\tag{1}$$
Assuming no heat losses (adiabatic system), then:
$$\text{d}Q=m_1c_1\text{d}T_1=-m_2c_2\text{d}T_2$$
$$m_1c_1\frac{\text{d}T_1}{\text{d}t}=-hA(T_1-T_2)\tag{2}$$
$$-m_2c_2\frac{\text{d}T_2}{\text{d}t}=-hA(T_1-T_2)\tag{3}$$
Divide $(2)$ by $(3)$:
$$-\frac{m_1c_1\text{d}T_1}{m_2c_2\text{d}T_2}=1$$
$$\text{d}T_1=-\alpha \text{d}T_2\tag{4}$$
Where:
$$\alpha=\frac{m_2c_2}{m_1c_1}$$
Integrate $(4)$:
$$\int\text{d}T_1=\int-\alpha \text{d}T_2\to T_1=-\alpha T_2+C_1$$
Determine integration constant $C_1$ from initial conditions:
$$T_{1,0}=-\alpha T_{2,0}+C_1$$
$$C_1=T_{1,0}+\alpha T_{2,0}$$
Insert all this into $(3)$:
$$-m_2c_2\text{d}T_2=-hA(-\alpha T_2+C_1-T_2)\text{d}t$$
$$m_2c_2\text{d}T_2=hA[C_1-(\alpha +1)T_2]\text{d}t\tag{5}$$
Make a simple substitution:
$$u=C_1-(\alpha +1)T_2$$
So that:
$$\text{d}u=-(\alpha +1)\text{d}T_2\to \text{d}T_2=-\frac{1}{\alpha +1}\text{d}u$$
Insert into $(5)$:
$$-\frac{1}{\alpha +1}\frac{{d}u}{u}=hA\text{d}t$$
$$-\frac{1}{\alpha +1}\int_{u_0}^{u(t)}\frac{{d}u}{u}=\int_0^t hA\text{d}t$$
$$\ln\frac{u(t)}{u_0}=-(\alpha +1)hAt$$
$$\frac{u(t)}{u_0}=\exp[-(\alpha +1)hAt]$$
$$\frac{C_1-(\alpha +1)T_2(t)}{C_1-(\alpha +1)T_{2,0}}=\exp[-(\alpha +1)hAt]$$
$$\boxed{T_2(t)=\frac{1}{\alpha +1}\Big[C_1-(\alpha+1)T_{2,0}\exp[-(\alpha +1)hAt]\Big]}$$

So that clearly the water temperature $T_2$ evolves at an exponential rate. At $t=+\infty$ both temperatures of $\text{Al}$ and water will have become equal and invariant. These final temperatures will be independent of both $h$ and $A$.

$$t=+\infty \to C_1-(\alpha +1)T_{2,\infty}=0$$
$$T_{1,0}+\alpha T_{2,0}-(\alpha +1)T_{2,\infty}=0$$
$$T_{2,\infty}=\frac{T_{1,0}+\alpha T_{2,0}}{\alpha +1}$$

We can also determine the cooling rate:

$$\boxed{\frac{\text{d}T_2(t)}{\text{d}t}=-(\alpha+1)T_{2,0}hA\exp[-(\alpha +1)hAt]}$$

Clearly, the cooling rate is **proportional to $A$**.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion and the proof. Sorry for my bad English (I have a bit of trouble understanding some part), are you suggesting that the weird temperature curve is due to the localised boiling? And also I am looking at the time at which the heat transfer is completed (or approximately completed).

Comment: I don't know what caused the blip but localised boiling **may** be it. In theory the heat transfer is completed after $t=+\infty$ and is independent from both $A$ and $h$. So it's better to measure water temperature after a short while, when heat transfer is still in progress.

Comment: But why does the weird curve only occur to the 4cm x 4cm piece but the other pieces (8cm x 4cm and 12cm x 4cm) does not have the weird curve and have the characteristic of exponential decay as you've suggested.

Comment: If you suspect a data point is faulty the rule in experimentation is to repeat that specific experiment. Flukes do occur and can be very difficult to explain rationally.